# Extracting Tables from MS Project Online

Tags: odata, qlikview, ms-project, ms-project-server-2013

I've been working on a project extracting all the database from Project Online and loading it in Qlikview. I have been able to extract almost all the data from it using the OData Protocol (which is not simple at all).

**My question is**:

Where all the assignments day by day are stored?

I know that in theory it should be in AssignmentTimephasedDataSet but not all the information its contained there. There's a lot of table with TimephasedDataSet info but I think that the Assignments day by day that are shown in Project Online should be in one specific Table.

So far I only can see the day by day assignments of couple of resources only.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The day by day details of assignments are stored in the same table that you mentioned in the question, which is `AssignmentTimephasedDataSet`. You can view the data Project-Wise or Resource-Wise using `ProjectName/ProjectID` and `ResourceID` Respectively.